# How can I clear my cache so that successive randomized queries return different results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, random

I would like to call this multiple times and have it return different results, but (I think) the cache is causing it to return the same result over and over:

```
randomMatchups = Matchup.order("RANDOM()")
```

I tried using:

```
uncached do
    randomMatchups = Matchup.order("RANDOM()")
end
```

and

```
matchup.connection.clear_query_cache
```

and

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_query_cache
```

and have had no luck so far.

Please note that this issue only arises in production (Heroku), and is not a problem when running locally.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I get different results when I refresh the page, but when I get to the controller via an AJAX request it does not work.

Comment: Would `RANDOM()+N` where N is a random number fix this?

Comment: It might, but where would I store that number between requests?

Comment: Why would you want to store it? The idea here is to bust the cache if that's the problem. If you're getting different results on refresh vs. AJAX calls, look very closely at `log/development.log` to see *exactly* what query is being run.

Comment: This problem does not happen in development, it only happens in production (deployed on Heroku).

Comment: @jackerman09 I've augmented my answer to cover AJAX caching too.

Comment: You need to narrow down this to see if it's cached in the browser, or cached in something server side. Are you sure the AJAX call is actually hitting the server? Are you sure nothing's being cached on the server? Check that `log/production.log` is showing activity on your AJAX call, and also check your network activity via Firebug, etc.

Comment: @tadman, the AJAX call is definitely hitting the server, as several other processes are executing that are within the same controller action. My `log/production.log` file is blank, any idea why this would be?

Comment: That could be a Heroku thing, as the way applications are deployed there is a little different from normal. You should try to reproduce this locally, perhaps using a VM with a production environment on it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe uncached, a class method on your model, should work like so:

```
randomMatchups = Matchup.uncached do
  Matchup.order("RANDOM()")
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-uncached

**EDIT:**

I see your edit with another probable solution. Your browser may well be caching the response. If you are using jQuery, set the cache option to false.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false
})
```

jQuery will add a GET parameter with a timestamp "_={timestamp}", which prevents the browser from caching the response.

If you aren't using jQuery look for an equivalent solution or simply append a timestamp yourself:

```
 <%= foo_path(timestamp: Time.now.to_f) %>
```

Comment: I tried this and it caused randomMatchups to be nil. Any idea why this would happen?